# Change mapped ip in wordpress docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm a little bit newbie with Docker. The problem is my server provider changed the public IP recently. When I ran my wordpress container I used the following:

```
docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxx --name wordpress-xx --link wordpressdb-xx -p 185.166.xx.xx:8081:80 -v "$PWD/docker/data/wordpress/xx":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

How can I change the old IP in order to assign the new one in a container that is already running?

Is it possible to run this containers with localhost IP? For example:

```
    docker run -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=xxx --name wordpress-xx --link wordpressdb-xx -p 127.0.0.1:8081:80 -v "$PWD/docker/data/wordpress/xx":/var/www/html -d wordpress
```

Comment: Why are you passing a specific IP:port to the -p param? Do you have more than one network interface on the machine? If not could you just map it as 127.0.0.1:8081:80 when you run the container?

Comment: nope. Can I just pass the ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to save the current container as an image using `docker commit` and then run the image as a new container with the new IP.

If you have only a single network interface just pass the port only. You can also use the 127.0.0.1 address

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose